# Mysql dump command similar in MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, batch-file

I need to automate a backup of some data from my database in SQL Server through bat file using a sql server command similar do mysql dump.

I already tried this with a bat file:

```
@echo off

cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
sqlcmd -i testequery.sql -S localhost -d xxx -U sa -P xxx -o TestResults.txt
```

But the result isn't in SQL:

> RA_FILIAL RA_MAT RA_NOME                        RA_ITEM        RA_ADMISSA >RA_DEMISSA RA_SITFOLH
>
> ---
>
> 0100      000677 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  10101001       19990607
>   0100      000989 zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz  10101001       20111003   20150410   D

I would like something in SQL style, to use that dump in another system with MySQL:

```
insert into table xxx values xxx
```

is that possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct command AFAIK but you have a couple of options

SQL Server Approach

> In SQL Server Management Studio right-click your database and select Tasks / Generate Scripts. Follow the wizard and you'll get a script that recreates the data structure in the correct order according to foreign keys. On the wizard step titled "Set Scripting Options" choose "Advanced" and modify the "Types of data to script" option to "Schema and data"

This is a C# project that can be compiled to dump your data

http://sqlserverdump.codeplex.com/